# Can I precede a noun with more than one determiner?

Tags: grammar, determiners

Is there a rule that a noun would take only one determiner at most?

For example, according to “[Determiner](http://www.englishlanguageguide.com/english/grammar/determiner.asp)” at *EnglishLanguageGuide.com*, both *both* and *the* are determiners. Can I write an expression like *the both cats*? Or do I have to use it in either *the cats* or *both cats* forms only?

Is this usage correct?

> I saw two cats this morning. The both cats were very young.

Comment: You may find [this discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2078486) interesting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, more than one determiner can precede a noun, but they do so in a particular order. *All, both* and *half* come before articles, so your example would have to read *I saw two cats this morning. Both the cats were very young* (but in this case *the* can be omitted).

Comment: Apparently, this applies only to 'Standard' English (whatever that would be) and more likely, BrE. @jwpat7 suggests an AmE usage in his answer below.

Comment: @Kris: 'The both of them' might also be found ocasionally in BrEng as an alternative to 'the two', but I was answering the question as put. It was about more than one determiner preceding a noun, and not about what might happen when no noun follows 'both'. In earlier times, incidentally, 'both' was actually placed between 'the' and the noun, as in, for example, 'To plate the both horns round about with gold.'

Answer (score 10):

As noted in previous answer, “Both the...” is standard.  However, in many cases of spoken (*vs* written) English, one finds “the both *of them/you/us*” being used where “both the” would be standard.

Merriam-Webster's **Dictionary of English Usage** has half a dozen paragraphs under [*both*, sense 5](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=%22the+both+of+them%22&source=bl&ots=nZtVmjB4_3&sig=jT0rUKEFmfdOj40OhBZ-HYqurbI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VP5CULaxJYLfiALS7oGQCw&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20both%20of%20them%22&f=false), with examples including  “the both of you” and “the both of them”.  It concludes:

> The expression appears to be an Americanism ... There is no reason you should avoid it if it is your normal idiom.

Note, Merriam-Webster's advice does not countenance saying “The both cats were...”, but would allow certain Americans to say “I saw two cats.  The both of them were white with spots of gray.”

Comment: Note that "both of them" would not be a replacement of just "both the", it would replace "both the cats" (Your example demonstrates that, but the first paragraph does not). While some people might say "both of them cats", it would be considered poor english.

Comment: Note that *the both of them* is permissible in American English, but not *the both of the cats* or *the both the cats*. So here you have a pronoun which cannot be replaced by its antecedent.